# if such $a^2+b^2+c^2+1=d+\sqrt{a+b+c-d}$ show $2(a+b+c)=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, radicals, substitution

Let $a,b,c,d\in R$ and such
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+1=d+\sqrt{a+b+c-d}$$
show that $$2(a+b+c)=3$$

It seem can use inequality to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a+b+c-d=x^2$, where $x\geq0$.

Hence, $$a^2+b^2+c^2+1=a+b+c-x^2+x$$ or
$$x^2-x+a^2+b^2+c^2-a-b-c+1=0$$ or
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=0,$$
which gives $a=b=c=\frac{1}{2}$ and $2(a+b+c)=3$.

Done!

Comment: To further clarify on this answer, in the final step, each term must be greater than or equal to zero since each term is squared. But they can't be positive, else they wouldn't sum to zero. Thus, each piece must equal zero.